# React Native iOS read image from apps Documents folder

Tags: ios, react-native

I have to download images to my iOS apps local file system and read them back.

On my simulator I can see file system of my app with directories

```
/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[UUID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[UUID]/

/Documents
/Library
/tmp
```

To try out I copied foo.png to /Documents folder and then tried

```
<Image source={{uri: "file://Documents/foo.png"}} style={{width:100, height:100}}/>
```

This does not work, any idea whats a way to do this.

Comment: You mean to get image from document directory in sandbox right..??

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This also took me ages... with better info it would have been 5 minutes!

I use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) to get directories (which works for ios and android):

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');
```

RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath then returns something like `'/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/15AC1CC6-8CFF-48F0-AFFD-949368383ACB/Documents'` on iOS

My Image element looks like:

```
<Image
    style={{width:100, height:100}}
    source={{uri: 'file://' + RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/myAwesomeSubDir/my.png', scale:1}}
/>
```

My problem was that I did not set width and height first, which is not needed for urls or paths to assets. When using a base64 uri the width and height are also mandatory (that actually led me to the solution!).

Comment: what is 'myAwesomeSubDir' ? is that the folder that created with the name of application?

Comment: As you can see in my answer, RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath returns you the path to the documents directory. Your file might be directly under that directory or in a subdirectory.... So just leave that part out if your files are stored  directly in the documents folder!

Comment: for me it was a similar situation. Saving the filename for the file in the docs dir and then rebuilding the full path at run time. I could be wrong but the docs dir and parents dirs may move around / change location / uuids.

Comment: I actually had the path already that I got with react-native-image-crop-picker and didn't need react-native-fs, i just didn't set the width and height! Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Try tilda (~). React Native should expand that.

```
<Image
   style={{width:100, height:100}}
   source={{uri: '~/Documents/myAwesomeSubDir/my.png', scale:1}}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This saves my day