# React Native: Set Array Length to File Count

Tags: react-native

My React Native project root directory contains counter.js and a folder containing multiple images.

How do I use counter.js to count the number of images in the folder?

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you can use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) library to read your image from your system. You must have more effort to explore about that and you can also to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286211/react-native-ios-read-image-from-apps-documents-folder) for other reference to use it.

I hope this answer can give you idea.

Comment: I've been reading about that and still don't understand how to use it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Ya i am sorry but i also have never used it.