# react-native-image-picker - persistent storage after rebuild

Tags: ios, react-native, persistence, react-native-image-picker

I've been hitting my head on the screen for some time and just can't get it to work despite all the information I've found on git or stackoverflow.

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

Persistence of the images selected (from library or camera). Persistence also when I rebuild my app, which means when I run `react-native run-ios` for iOS, or `react-native run-android` for Android.

**What I've implemented**

Here is my function that is called when I add an image.

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker({
   storageOptions: {
      path: 'myCustomPath',
      waitUntilSaved: true,
      cameraRoll: true,
      skipBackup : true
   },
   noData: true
}, res => {
   if (res.didCancel) {
      console.log("User cancelled");
   } else if (res.error) {
      console.log("Error", res.error);
   } else {
      console.log("Picker Response:", res);
      // Getting the fileName as for iOS the fileName is incorrect even with waitUntilSaved to true.
      const path = res.uri.split("/");
      const fileName = path[path.length-1]; 
      let uri = "file://" + Platform.select({
         android: RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/Pictures/",
         ios: RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath+"/"
         })
         + "myCustomPath/" + fileName

      this.setState({
         pickedImage: {
            uri: uri,
         }
      });
      this.props.onImagePicked({ uri: res.uri }); 
   }
});
```

And in my home page, I display the image in `<Thumbnail square style={{width:50, height:50}} source={info.item.image} />`

---- EDIT START -----
---- SOLUTION ----

The solution was to reconstruct the path where I want to display the image using the fileName:
`<Thumbnail square style={{width:50, height:50}} source={{uri : RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath+"/"+info.item.image.fileName}} />`

---- EDIT ENDS -----

**The Result**

So here are the results, you'll see works well on Android, but not on iOS.
I selected an image on the library using the `react-native-image-picker`.

**Android**

"Picker Response":

```
fileName: "image-d53839d1-fa89-4a61-b648-f74dace53f83.jpg"
fileSize: 235728
height: 1440
isVertical: true
originalRotation: 0
path: "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myCustomPath/image-d53839d1-fa89-4a61-b648-f74dace53f83.jpg"
type: "image/jpeg"
uri: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myCustomPath/image-d53839d1-fa89-4a61-b648-f74dace53f83.jpg"
width: 1080
```

the save "uri" for my image is : `file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/myCustomPath/image-d53839d1-fa89-4a61-b648-f74dace53f83.jpg`

Behavior is as below :

- left screenshot is after saving my image,
- right screenshot is after a rebuild, opening the app, I still see my image!

--> Happy!

[image]
[image]

**Now on iOS**

"Picker Response" :

```
fileName: "IMG_0004.JPG"
fileSize: 470300
height: 1618
isVertical: true
latitude: 64.752895
longitude: -14.538611666666666
origURL: "assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=99D53A1F-FEEF-40E1-8BB3-7DD55A43C8B7&ext=JPG"
timestamp: "2012-08-08T21:29:49Z"
type: "image/jpeg"
uri: "file:///Users/[name]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33076AD2-C989-47E9-A803-3E56CC4B09D6/data/Containers/Data/Application/4756F0A2-9CCC-4F9A-9315-D55434328FD9/Documents/myCustomPath/6A5C27E3-89F7-465F-A855-66749C92D086.jpg"
width: 1080
```

the save "uri" for my image is : `file:///Users/[name]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33076AD2-C989-47E9-A803-3E56CC4B09D6/data/Containers/Data/Application/4756F0A2-9CCC-4F9A-9315-D55434328FD9/Documents/myCustomPath/6A5C27E3-89F7-465F-A855-66749C92D086.jpg`

Behavior is as below :

- left screenshot is after saving my image,
- right screenshot is after a rebuild, opening the app, I still see my image!

--> **NOT HAPPY!**

[image]
[image]

**My issue**

I've read all about the temporary aspect of the returned uri and see what `react-native-image-picker` says about it:

> On iOS, don't assume that the absolute uri returned will persist.

I've found also this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286211/react-native-ios-read-image-from-apps-documents-folder%5D) which had a similar issue, but none worked:

- `RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath` after a rebuild had a different UUID in the path, so the file was not found as it was saved with the previous UUID
- I tried saving for iOS the uri as '~/Documents/myCustomPath/myfilename.jpg' had the same behavior. Displayed when added, blank after rebuild.

I had before the rebuild:

Document directory path being :
 `file:///Users/[user]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33076AD2-C989-47E9-A803-3E56CC4B09D6/data/Containers/Data/Application/466CAF1A-AF8D-423C-9BF6-F0A242AF8038/Documents/`

and my saved picture uri :

`file:///Users/[user]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33076AD2-C989-47E9-A803-3E56CC4B09D6/data/Containers/Data/Application/466CAF1A-AF8D-423C-9BF6-F0A242AF8038/Documents/myCustomPath/20969988-633B-46BD-8558-E39C3ADD6D12.jpg`

but after the rebuild the Application UUID changed to `BEE128C8-5FCF-483C-A829-8F7A0BB4E966` making now my document directory to be

`file:///Users/[user]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33076AD2-C989-47E9-A803-3E56CC4B09D6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/BEE128C8-5FCF-483C-A829-8F7A0BB4E966/Documents`

but still looking the picture in the uri :

`file:///Users/[user]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33076AD2-C989-47E9-A803-3E56CC4B09D6/data/Containers/Data/Application/466CAF1A-AF8D-423C-9BF6-F0A242AF8038/Documents/myCustomPath/20969988-633B-46BD-8558-E39C3ADD6D12.jpg`

When the image is actually now located under:

`file:///Users/[user]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33076AD2-C989-47E9-A803-3E56CC4B09D6/data/Containers/Data/Application/BEE128C8-5FCF-483C-A829-8F7A0BB4E966/Documents/myCustomPath/20969988-633B-46BD-8558-E39C3ADD6D12.jpg`

So how can I cope for that App UUID change after a rebuild as paths are dynamic on iOS.

**Versions I use:**

- "react-native": "0.57.8",
- "react-native-fs": "^2.13.2",
- "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.0"

Comment: What do you mean by a rebuild? Do you mean a reload `CMD+R`? Or do you mean deleting the app from the simulator and rebuilding it and reinstalling it?  Have you tried going to the documents directory on the simulator and seeing if the image is there? Have you tried using `RNFS.readDir` to check that the images are there?

Comment: I mean by rebuild running: ```react-native run-ios```. 

Reloads (```CMD+R```) do work.
Desinstall of course looses persistence.
But I need to keep persistence when rebuilding (kind of when you get a new build version)

Comment: ok, for ```RNFS.readDir``` in my ```myCustomPath``` I do get the image from my previous example, with the path:
```/Users/johanmontmartin/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/33076AD2-C989-47E9-A803-3E56CC4B09D6/data/Containers/Data/Application/A4CE9AE7-D766-4949-B380-9642138D7C58/Documents/myCustomPath/6A5C27E3-89F7-465F-A855-66749C92D086.jpg``` but as we can see the ```Application``` GUID in the path is not the same, because is regenerated with new builds.

Comment: So the file exists but it has a different url?

Comment: Correct. Which is the issue many people have usually after a rebuild because everytime with a rebuild, the app internal id changes (see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286211/react-native-ios-read-image-from-apps-documents-folder] (this stackoverflow thread), but this didn't help me)

Comment: also same issue as in [https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-image-picker/issues/107]

Comment: Why doesn’t the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286211/react-native-ios-read-image-from-apps-documents-folder%5D work for you? You may need to share more code or explain what is happening in more detail in your code after you select the image.

Comment: the solution doesn't work because RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath after a rebuild returns the new application UUID, so the path to the original image was lost.
For the tilda solution (~), that did not work as the image was not even showing.

Comment: ok... I think I got my issue, I was not regenerating the path when I wanted to display the image... will try and update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `react-native-image-picker` states

> On iOS, don't assume that the absolute uri returned will persist.

This means that if you store the absolute uri to the file and then do `react-native run-ios` the application GUID will change and that absolute uri will no longer exist or work. However, and this is **important** the image will be in the folder that you saved it in, as it is copied across.

The only solution to fixing this is to save the directory and the filename of the file and reconstruct the uri when you want to use it.

So that means that you would save in state

```
this.setState({ image: '/myCustomPath/image.jpg' });
```

Then when you come to use it you would rebuild the path like this

```
let pathToFile = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}${this.state.image}`
```

Comment: Correct, that is what I've figured out and just tested. My issue is I was not reconstructing the path when I display the image: What worked was ```source={{uri : RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath+"/"+info.item.image.fileName}}```

Answer (score 2):

You could simply solve this (without rely on react-native-fs) by replacing the path before "/Documents/..." with a tilde "~".

```
let pathToFile = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/9793A9C3-C666-4A0E-B630-C94F02E32BE4/Documents/images/72706B9A-12DF-4196-A3BE-6F17C61CAD06.jpg"
if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    pathToFile = '~' + pathToFile.substring(pathToFile.indexOf('/Documents'));
}
```

This is supported by React Native as you can see in their [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/23909cd6f62056de0cd0f7c06e3997dd967c139a).