# react native Image doesn't render local source

Tags: ios, react-native

```
// write image to local path
  NSString *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES).firstObject;
  NSString *filePath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"a.jpg"]];
  [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES]

// under iOS (it works great)
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: filePath];

// under react native (Could not find image filePath)
<Image source={{ uri:  filePath }} />
```

This is the result
[no image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3GyV.jpg)

Anyone has the same issues?

---

I gave this a shot, but no good!

```
<Image style={{width:100, height:100}} source={{ uri: 'file://' + RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/myAwesomeSubDir/my.png', scale:1}} />
```

---

**I knew why Image doesn't render the source, cuz the source path has no extension name! [Image doesn't render local source (path with no extension name)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23844)**

Comment: In iOS you cannot guarantee that the filePath to the image is constant between builds. Every time you run `react-native run-ios` the file path will change. This means that you have to construct the filePath each time you want to use the file. You cannot hardcore the filePath.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, under ios `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imagePath]` everything goes well. Is there a way to solve it?

Comment: How are you saving the image to the device? Are you saving it in the native or JavaScript side?

Comment: @Andrew I'm using a native instant messaging Framework! The framework save image to device.  I write the chat UI by React native.

Comment: If you look at the native code it is constructing the image path, you need to do the same. This may mean you need to install a dependency like `react-native-fs` or `rn-fetch-blob` that will give you access to the device filesystem. Using one of those you should be able to create the correct file path to the image. see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286211/react-native-ios-read-image-from-apps-documents-folder/45378735) for an example

Comment: @Andrew I'll give it a shot! Thanks. I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: @Andrew No good!

Comment: @DavidLee I am also having a problem in iOS (not on android), accessing files stored locally such as file:///data/user/0/com.xxxx/files/productdata_da13681addffaed7622ece9b2bb56e22bc65f6b9.jpg. I tried to access such files in the browser, couldn't as well. Any idea?